# How to filter and label messages as "INTERNAL-ONLY" and "EXTERNAL

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, google-workspace-for-business

I'd like to create a pair of labels.

One would be "INTERNAL-ONLY".  This label should match email threads that only include senders and receivers on the thread whose mail domain, @example.com, match my domain.

The second would be "EXTERNAL".  This label should match the disjoint set.  These are email threads that contain *anyone* in the sender or receipient list whose mail domain is anything other than @example.com.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to create an Inbound [Content Compliance](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934) rule that matches all mail and delivers it with modifications with the action being prepend a custom subject with EXTERNAL.

Comment: This answers a different question.  The question was about applying a `gmail-label` to messages not editing the subject.